# Martingale assumption

Tags: martingales, expected-value

In a proof that I'm reading I notice the following:
Assume $M$ is a positive martingale with $E[M_t^2]= \frac1t$ then, by Jensen inequality:
$$0\le \big(E[M_t]\big)^2\le E[M_t^2]= \frac1t\to0$$ when $t \to \infty$. This implies that $E[M_t]=0$ for all $t\ge1$

My question is: where did I use the assumption that M is a martingale. I guess that is the fact that a martingale has equal expectation for each $t$ . But still is not clear to me.

My interpretation is: $E[M_\infty]^2=0$ imply $E[M_\infty]=0 $ and then $E[M_t]=0$ for each $t$?  However, doesn't I need to use some convergence theorem for obtain this result?

Is it true that for a martingale $E[M_\infty]=E[M_t]$?

Comment: If $M$ is a martingale with finite second moments, then $M^2_t$ is a submartingale, so $E[M^2_t]$ is an *increasing* function of $t$. The situation you have presented is therefore *impossible*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any martingale $M,$ we have for $s \leq t$

\begin{align*}
E|M_t| &= E[E|M_t||\mathscr{F}_s]  \tag*{(tower property)} \\
&\geq E|E [ M_t| \mathscr{F}_s]|  \tag*{(Jensen's inequality)}  \\
&= E|M_s|.      \tag*{(M is a martingale)}
\end{align*}

This means that $\sup_{t \geq 0} E|M_t| = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} E|M_t|.$

Also, from your question we know

$$0\leq \big(E[M_t]\big)^2\le E[M_t^2]= \frac1t,$$ 
Hence, $0 \leq E|M_t| < \frac{1}{t^2},$ and 
$$\sup_{t \geq 0} E|M_t|=\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} E|M_t| = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t^2} = 0.$$ 
Therefore, $E|M_t| = 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: why did you take the absolute value. I think that from here $0\leq \big(E[M_t]\big)^2\le E[M_t^2]= \frac1t,$ we could just notice that $E[M_t]^2$ is an increasing function of t, so if his limit is equal to $0$ then, being the limit = sup, we have that $E[M_t]^2 = 0$ for each t, that imply $E[M_t] = 0$ for each t. doesn't work like this?

Comment: What I did is correct but yes, you can also conclude as you said. It's a matter of taste I guess.